# How can I disable Facebook API alerts?

Tags: android, facebook

I am building an Android app using PhoneGap with facebook-connect-plugin to login with Facebook. Everything works just fine, but I face a problem when the user cancels (e.g presses the device back button in the Facebook app), and the login window which view an alert with a message "cardova login fail!Cancelled".

I don't have any solution to handle the situation (if you have one, please suggest) so I want to disable the alert (I don't want the user to see Facebook API alert) and use FB.getLoginStatus to check if user has logged in.

Comment: Any luck? I'm having the same problem...